# Recursive Relationship in Realm Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, realm, relationships

If I wish to have a Realm array of the same user model, an exception occurs.
 `RLMException(@"RLMArray properties require a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>.");`
So is there a workaround? How can a recursive relationship be implemented in Realm as below?

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
@interface User : RLMObject
@property NSInteger userId;
@property NSString *displayName;
@property RLMArray<User> *friends;
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data;
@end  
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE (User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception says, you need to declare a protocol to define the contained type of the `RLMArray`. This is what the `RLM_ARRAY_TYPE` macro does. The special thing here is that you need to put this declaration before your interface declaration, which can be done by pre-declaring the `User` type with `@class`. You can do it like this :

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@class User;
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE (User)

@interface User : RLMObject
@property NSInteger userId;
@property NSString *displayName;
@property RLMArray<User> *friends;
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data;
@end
```

Comment: The realm documentation says that we should add the macro at the end of bottom of the model interface.
And yes forward declaration is the solution in addition to adding the macro on top. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

I Think the terminology is **"Inverse Relationships"**, I never tried to reference and object with nested objects of the same class.
But in Realm Documentary, they have an example of and "dog" and "owner".
The owner can have dogs, and the dogs can have owners and they have a **"Inverse Relationships"**.

It should look like this:

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSInteger age;
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *owners;
@end

@implementation Dog
+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{
        @"owners": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:Person.class propertyName:@"dogs"],
    };
}
@end
```

ref: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#relationships

Comment: I think this solution should also work based on a more clearer example in this article 
https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.100.0/